# Can we add luggage tags to the shop inventory?

Tags: discussion

My eye just fell on my backpack and the flyertalk luggage tag on it. I have barely visited FT since I lost interest in chasing status about a year ago. I would love to replace that tag with a T.SE one - featuring perhaps my handle, my fave tags, or the little flair that shows badge counts. I just checked, and the store doesn't have them.

Once we get our "look" decided, can we celebrate by getting luggage tags added to the store?

Comment: I think it is a really good idea, but I'm not sure if it is possible? Another problem is that the flair is changing all the time, so you would have to renew your tag every then. Or do you want electronic tags? :D

Comment: Ideally the tags would be quite inexpensive and we could order new ones once a year or so as we gained more badges. Obviously showing your actual rep is impractical. Perhaps people might buy them as they passed certain milestones? 5K+ etc?

Answer (score 2):

Awesome idea!

But also a sew-on cloth patch version for backpacks!